# How to Pass QMainWindow mouse clicked position to QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsview

I have a display window like this:

[image]

Above display widgets are `QGraphicsView` widgets (they are in a `QGridLayout`) and what I want to achieve is that:

when user click in `MainWindow`, I want to seize that clicked position and decide which `QGraphicsView` widget contains that position and set the border of that selected `QGraphicsView` widget to green color. And only one `QGraphicView` widget can be selected at a time.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just reimplement `mousePressEvent`. Focus handling can also be a case.

Comment: @ilotXXI reimplement `mousePressEvent` in `MainWindow` or in each of the `QGraphicView` widget ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for your `QGraphicsViews` and detect mouse press events on them. So, you can define current view and make border for it as you want. Small example:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event) override;


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsView* view1_;
    QGraphicsView* view2_;
    QGraphicsView* selectedView_;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
        view1_(nullptr),
        view2_(nullptr),
        selectedView_(nullptr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
        QGridLayout* grid = new QGridLayout(this->centralWidget());
        view1_ = new QGraphicsView(this);
        view2_ = new QGraphicsView(this);
        grid->addWidget(view1_, 0, 0);
        grid->addWidget(view2_, 0, 1);
        view1_->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
        view2_->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << event->type();
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        if (watched == view1_->viewport()){
            selectedView_ = view1_;
            QMessageBox::information(this, "!", "First");
            return false;
        }
        else if (watched == view2_->viewport()){
            selectedView_ = view2_; 
            QMessageBox::information(this, "!", "Second");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question: if I enable user to dynamically allocate the number of `QGraphicsView` widget in the `QGridLayout`. Then, is there an appropriate way to deal with the same selection problem ? Your current implementation is for fixed number of `QGraphicsView` widget.

Comment: If user set dynamically number of QGraphicsViews, approch will be the same as for two widgets. Set event filter for each QGraphicsView and in eventFilter method determine which widget was selected. I don't see the problem. Can you describe what wiil be the difference?

Comment: I have question here. If user set dynamically number of `QGraphicsView`s, say 9, and then user change it to 4. Should I delete the previous 9 `QGraphicsView`s and re-new 4 `QGraphicsView`s and put them in a vector. (`std::vector<QGraphicsView *>`). Or is there a smarter way to do the dynamic allocation of `QGraphicsView`s

Comment: If you know max number of QGraphicsViews, which user can select, for example 9, you can create such number of QGraphicsViews objects and put them in vector. When user change number to 4, you can remove some QGraphicsViews from layout, but not from vector. I think, re-new objects every time, when user change number is not good, it's better create objects one time and then reuse.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the border color on mouse hover, you wouldn't need such complicated programming. Qt [supports](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) style sheets, just like CSS.

In this case, it's enough to attach the following stylesheet to your `MainWindow`.

```
QGraphicsView:hover {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: green;
}
```

[image]

There's two ways to get this done:

- Using the Designer: First select the `MainWindow` and then in its properties panel click on the `styleSheet` and copy and paste the style sheet.
- Using code: Use `setStyleSheet(...)` method of `QMainWindow` and pass the style sheet as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I have set a `QComboBox` to allow user to select the number of `QGraphicsView` widgets they need. For example, user set `QComboBox` to 9, then the above image is the result. Then, I want to decide which `QGraphicsView` widget the user has clicked and insert a video stream to that selected `QGraphicsView` widget.

Comment: @Johnnylin It's simple, just take a look at [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#details). For styling the border, the style sheets are okay.